# vb.net - How to make a "hub" or a main menu of multiple exe projects that will update independently?

Tags: vb.net

I have approx 22 vb.net windows form based projects that are run by different users throughout my company. I publish them using one-click to a network server, then install on each user computer using the set-up file on that server.  That way, when I publish an update, it is automatically pushed to each user when they open their programs.

I'd like to consolidate all of this into 1 program.  So for example, the Accounting dept, IT Dept, and Customer Service Dept would all have the same icon/program to open, and they choose which program specific to them to open from that main menu.  The goal is to remove all 22 programs from user computers and only have 1 installed that runs each individually (somehow).

My dilemma is program updates.  When I update a program for the Accounting Dept, IT doesn't need that update.  But since it would be only 1 installation and 1 publish, every user on the network would receive updates not relevant to them.  So how do I create one main program "hub" for all users that only receives updates to the programs that they need?

Comment: It seems like it's just a program to run programs. It would be a 23rd .exe file with it's own update. Instead of having the icons on the desktop it would be in that program. You can't easily combine all 22 programs into one big exe file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... yes I can't come up with any other ideas.  A 23rd program is pointless though because the other 22 would still need their own exe file installed.

Comment: I would ask if your users have requested such a feature?  Plus, it seems it would require an extra step for your users to access the application they want.  Why would the employee in the Account Dept. need to even see the icons for the apps that the IT dept. uses?  What if they try to run them?

Comment: The bosses like the idea of having one application for everyone to use.  In my mind, this is more of a web app request, but I'm doing my due diligence in researching ideas to make this happen.  I would have to have a user table that assigns permissions to specific programs, or maybe just button visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the click once programmatically

```
Dim url = "\\Software\Production\ClickOnceApp\ClickOnceApp.application"
Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication " & url)
```

Just point to the url on your server, where it's installed from. This will launch the app the same way windows does, so it would check for updates when it's run as if it's run from the start menu.

Then you could maintain a list of 22 applications' names and locations in the 23rd app's settings, xml, sql, etc., and add user groups, permissions, etc.

It could be a winforms app which provides buttons according to the configuration above for launching all these apps. Yes, I think this is actually a pretty neat idea.

Comment: Yes, this is the ticket, thanks.  I'm going to consolidate the department programs into 1 program per dept, then have a main menu that runs the code you suggested.  So each user will have a minimum of 2 programs installed - the main menu, and their dept program.  This allows programs to update independently, and it also allows users like myself to have access to all programs via one main menu.  Awesome.  Thanks!